# Is it Possible Paid app installed from play store after reinstalled from play store but second time not paid money?

Tags: android, google-play

App Published on Play store Paid App. User Paid app Installed in their Device from Play Store. Any other Reason app uninstalled from the Device. Again User installed app from the Play store and getting paid in Play store but I want not paid Second time for the one Year.

what will change in my app? How its Possible for my app?

Comment: You have to publish free app and set subscription in-App for one year.

Comment: one can reinstall app later without buying it again But on same play store account only... Go to link https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2521768?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If you choose that your application is paid for its publication, you can not pass it for free and it's the same in the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

When a user buys an app on the Play store, they are then allowed to re-install it on any device forever (as long as it is the same user account). This is just how Google Play works, you can't change it. See [the support docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113410)